# JavaScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined in internet explorer 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined in internet explorer 8?

> Login form
>               
>               
>    window.onload = function () {

```
        //Select the edit visitors Tab
        var siblings = ($("li.pull-right").siblings());

        for (var i = 0; i <= siblings.length - 1; i++) {
            console.log(siblings[i].innerText.trim().toLowerCase());
            if (siblings[i].innerText.trim().toLowerCase() == "edit visitors") {
                siblings[i].setAttribute("class", "active pull-right");
            } else {
                siblings[i].setAttribute("class", "pull-right");
            }
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-core nav-heros">
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="EditVisitor.aspx">Edit Visitors</a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="EditNews.aspx">Edit News</a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="SelectTemplate.aspx">Select Template</a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="Settings.aspx">Settings</a></li>
                    <li class="active pull-right"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: paste your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Remove `console.log(siblings[i].innerText.trim().toLowerCase());` line as IE doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `console.log` from your code, also you missed a `}` of `window.onload ()`,

Also use [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) in place of `window.onload` like

```
$(function () {
    var siblings = ($("li.pull-right").siblings());
    for (var i = 0; i <= siblings.length - 1; i++) {
        if (siblings[i].innerText.trim().toLowerCase() == "edit visitors") {
            siblings[i].setAttribute("class", "active pull-right");
        } else {
            siblings[i].setAttribute("class", "pull-right");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older browsers, they may not have a console.  Try doing:

```
if (window.console) {
    console.log(siblings[i].innerText.trim().toLowerCase());
```

Or maybe even globally setting it if it doesn't exist:

```
// In a JS file that loads early
if (!window.console) {
    window.console = { log: function() {} }; // For example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what browser are you using?

put this code into initial function in order to avoid calls from undefined refs

```
if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Older browsers like IE doesn't support console.log .

Better remove manually  , If you have so many console in your code

then use

```
if(typeof(console) === 'undefined') {
    var console = {}
    console.log = console.error = console.info = console.debug = console.warn = console.trace = console.dir = console.dirxml = console.group = console.groupEnd = console.time = console.timeEnd = console.assert = console.profile = function() {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE it will throw this error. Try this in chrome/firefox. Console is not part of the standard and is an extension of the DOM. You can use this to see if your browser supports it:-

```
function log(text) {
  if (window.console) {
     window.console.log(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```
window.onload = function () {
        var siblings = ( $("li.pull-right").siblings() );

            console.log( siblings.text().trim().toLowerCase() );
            if (siblings.text().trim().toLowerCase() == "edit visitors") {
                siblings.attr("class", "active pull-right");
            } else {
                siblings.attr("class", "pull-right");
            };
};
```

If you are using than no need to use the for loop to check the all 'li'. '.siblings' already select all the li element with the class name.